# Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes in plugin Accordion on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, accordion

I use the Accordion plugin of Wordpress in php. But after changing the name of the site, I have errors including the script add-acc.php.
The error message is:
 `Notice: unserialize (): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes`.
The line concerned in the file is:

```
$ accordion_data = unserialize (get_post_meta ($ post-> ID, 'wpsm_accordion_data', true));
```

I can not solve this problem. As a result, the publications do not appear anymore.

Can someone help me?

thank you in advance

Comment: `get_post_meta` should do the unserializing, but if it's a plugin I would consult the plugins support page ect...

Comment: What does this mean _changing the name of the site_???

Comment: I changed the url of the site. Everything works fine except this plugin that generates error messages.